# How to refer a table in Latex

Tags: cross-referencing

I have problem with referring tables in Latex. The output is always in form of "??" (see screeshot please). However, I got no problem with referring figures.

> is illustrated in Table \ref{table:a}:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.7in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.6in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.2in} |}
\hline
...
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:a}
\caption{Remote sensing image scene classification approaches}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: \label{table:a} must be behind the \caption command.

Comment: Thanks it works, I don't know how I didn't try that before, can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it as solution